# WPF user controls are not displaying correctly in Visual Studio 2022 XAML editor

Tags: wpf, user-controls, visual-studio-2022

I have recently started using Visual Studio 2022 for continuing to develop a long standing WPF project (originally developed in Visual Studio 2017, then more recently in Visual Studio 2019).

Everything seems OK with the project in VS2022 except for the fact that all the project's WPF user controls do not display correctly in the VS2022 XAML editor.  The project compiles correctly and the user controls display and operate correctly in the executable.

User controls show correctly in VS2019...

[image: User controls show correctly in VS2019]

User controls show incorrectly in VS2022...

[image: User controls show incorrectly in VS2022]

Selecting any control shows this error...

[image: Selecting any control shows this error]

I have tried recreating the controls in VS2022 but they continue not to display correctly when used in the XAML editor.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of VS 2022?

Comment: Some xaml would be useful. Maybe it's something trivial or it could be that the controls have 100s lines of code in them that should not be there. I have seen this when the controls have not been built. Try googling shadow cache in VS.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to recreate the project from scratch in VS2022, add all the references and NuGet packages, then copy and add all the code files from the VS2019 project into the new VS2022 project.

While doing this, I did not need to make any changes to project properties, target platform or the code files.  After adding all the code files and re-building, the XAML editor displayed the user controls correctly. The project also compiled and ran correctly.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: Interesting. I've had problems with files that display in VS 2019 but are completely blank in VS 2022. I will have to try this.